# Adding event listeners and internationalisation in DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, internationalization, datatables

I have problem with internationalisation in DataTables.

After creating a table in DataTables I want to bind an **change** event listener to **select** tag (number of elements). I have no problem with that, but when I use language options in DataTables I can't bind an event listener.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hus9oyfz/)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ex</title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" >
    var tableId = 0;

var keywords = [["dog", 2],["table", 3],["chair", 4],["dog", 2],["table", 3],["chair", 4], ["dog", 2],["table", 3],["chair", 4],["dog", 2],["table", 3],["chair", 4],["dog", 2],["table", 3],["chair", 4]];

    function buildKeywordTableString(keywords){

      var dataSet = new Array();

      for (var i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++){
          dataSet.push([keywords[i][0],keywords[i][1]]);    
            }

            var table =  '<table id="table' + tableId + '" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display"><thead><tr><th>K</th><th>F</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table>';


            return table;
        };

    $("body").append(buildKeywordTableString(keywords));

    $('#table' + tableId).dataTable({
        language: {
                url: '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Catalan.json'           },
            "data": keywords,
            "bFilter":true,
            "paging": true,
            "bPaginate":true,
            "columns": [
                {"title": "Keywords"},
                {"title": "F", "width": "80px"}]
        });

        var selectElement = document.getElementsByName('table' + tableId.toString() + '_length')[0];    
        selectElement.addEventListener('change',function(){

            var tableIde = $(this).attr('name').replace('_length', "");
            var table = $("#" + tableIde).DataTable();
            table.page.len(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text).draw();

        });

        tableId++;

    $("body").append(buildKeywordTableString(keywords));
$('#table' + tableId).dataTable({
            "data": keywords,
            "bFilter":true,
            "paging": true,
            "bPaginate":true,
            "columns": [
                {"title": "Keywords"},
                {"title": "F", "width": "80px"}]
        });

        var selectElement = document.getElementsByName('table' + tableId.toString() + '_length')[0];    
        selectElement.addEventListener('change',function(){

            var tableIde = $(this).attr('name').replace('_length', "");
            var table = $("#" + tableIde).DataTable();
            table.page.len(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text).draw();

        });

    tableId++;

</script>

  <div id="details"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

If language option

`language: {
                url: '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Catalan.json'           },`

is deleted, it works without problems, but i need internationalisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the Datatables [language.url documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.url):

> Note that when this parameter is set, DataTables' initialisation will
>   be asynchronous due to the Ajax data load. That is to say that the
>   table will not be drawn until the Ajax request as completed. As such,
>   any actions that require the table to have completed its
>   initialisation should be placed into the [initCompleteDT](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete) callback.

So the fact is that when you use the language.url, when you do

```
var selectElement = document.getElementsByName('table' + tableId.toString() + '_length')[0];
```

the table is not yet drawn and the dom elements does not exist.

So what you have to do here is to add to your settings object the "initComplete" attribute as a function which do what it has to do.

Comment: You are right, thank you. I will award your answer as soon as possible.